# Can an Arduino receive an integer and a float together?

Tags: arduino

I am working on a project where I have to receive a float value and an integer value. The float has to be saved and the integer value has to be used for another purpose.

Comment: Sorry but your question makes no sense. Please re-write it with more details and your current code.

Comment: How to ask: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: sorry, i need to get integers and string from serial.The received integer  are used for commands for the dc motors.And float values are used for storing gps co-ordinates.is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Usually an arduino does not receive any integers or floats at all. The usual way an arudino receives something is through the serial interface.
Data is sent as a sequence of bytes.
The meaning of that data is determined by the sender. You can receive monkeys and elephants with an arduino (virtual ones of course) as long as you know the protocol.

Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_asynchronous_receiver-transmitter
and get some basic knowledge in data types and how to communicate them through a serial interface.

You should define a protocol for your application or simply send the data as strings which you parse on-board.

Comment: sorry, i need to get integers and string from serial.The received integer  are used for commands for the dc motors.And float values are used for storing gps co-ordinates.is this possible?

Comment: @AhamedMaududi yes... get some knowledge in computing if you plan to do something in this domain.